# Finding what the limit is for this graph

Tags: calculus, limits

Basically, I am trying to answer this problem:

[image]

I need help with statement 3.

I know that statement 1 is true. F(1) = 1 and f ' (3) would be equal to a negative number since the slope of the tangent line on f is negative. This makes this statement true as 1 > a negative number.

I also know that statement 2 is true. F ' (3.5) would be equal to zero since f(3.5) has a horizontal tangent. Since we know this, we automatically know that the integral will have a positive number. This makes this statement true as a positive number > 0.

I do not understand what statement 3 means. I have tried plugging in the values but I get stuck.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: To begin with, it's worth mentioning that your argument for $2$ only works because the function is strictly positive over the range of integration. (you probably knew that but just in case) For $3,$ I think a logical way to do it would be to look at the concavity of the graph for the sign of the second derivative, which tells you how the derivative changes near that point.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f\left(2+h\right)-f\left(2\right)}{h}=f'\left(2\right)
$$
and if i'm not mistaken
$$
\frac{f\left(2.5\right)-f\left(2\right)}{2.5-2}=\frac{1}{2.5-2}\int_{2}^{2.5}f'\left(t\right)\text{d}t$$
which is the mean value of $f'$ over $\left[2,2.5\right]$.
When can you say that the mean value of $f'$ on $\left[a;b\right]$ is more than $f'\left(a\right)$ ?

Comment: I understand your process but not your question. Could you rephrase it by any chance? Thanks.

Comment: This is actually pretty much what I was thinking as well: given the concavity of the graph, what can you say about the values that $f'$ takes on the region $[2, 2.5]$ in relation to $f'(2)?$ What does this tell you about the average value of $f'$ on this interval?

Comment: The mean value theorem is more when f ' is increasing in the interval from a to b.

Comment: You are right @EdmondHelen, but as Stephen Donovan mentioned, what can you say about the position of the tangent at a point $x_0 \in \left[2,2.5\right]$ compared to the graph itself ?

Comment: The graph has a tangent somewhere in (a,b) that is parallel to the secant line over [a,b].

Comment: Have you seen the notion of concavity and convexity ?

Comment: I know of concavity but not of convexity.

Comment: They're opposite, concavity of $f$ is equivalent to $-f$ is convex. Here you can see the concavity of $f$ over $\left[2,2.5\right]$. It means that $f'$ is decreasing on $\left[2,2.5\right]$.